# How to add LWC/Aura dynamic App Builder component properties?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, design-attributes, dynamic-design-attributes-rendering

I am looking for ways to create Design Properties for an Aura or LWC component so that I can render different values in component properties based on chosen value in one property.

Something very similar to how standard **Related Lists - Single** component works. Whenever we change **Parent Record** value, the **Related List** dropdown values change accordingly.

How can I do this? I've been looking for this kind of functionality for so long and didn't noticed Salesforce already did in there proprietary base standard component. This is one feature that should be made available to developers on priority I would think ...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is currently nothing more than an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CTa2QAG) (make sure you go vote for this!). Unfortunately, you can't do this today, nor is there a known timeline for this feature (future readers: if this comes out, remind me to edit this answer).